# (Im)mutability of OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddict

Is Python's `OrderedDict` data structure a mutable collection?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) does not say anything about it, and after a quick search on the web, I have not found any answer yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The documentation does not say anything about it, and after a quick
> search on the web, I have not found any answer yet.

When in doubt regarding mutability of class you might run following test

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections.abc import MutableSequence, MutableSet, MutableMapping
print(issubclass(OrderedDict,(MutableSequence,MutableSet,MutableMapping)))
```

output

```
True
```

See [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) in `collections.abc` docs for other things which can be checked this way.

Answer (score 2):

From [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-ordereddict/#managing-items-in-an-ordereddict):

> Since OrderedDict is a *mutable* data structure, you can perform
> mutating operations on its instances. You can insert new items, update
> and remove existing items, and so on. If you insert a new item into an
> existing ordered dictionary, then the item is added to the end of the
> dictionary:

They provide a couple of examples for *mutable* operations like insert:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> numbers = OrderedDict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
>>> numbers
OrderedDict([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)])

>>> numbers["four"] = 4
>>> numbers
OrderedDict([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4)])
```

Generally, if a datatype supports the following [operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), then it is considered a mutable sequence type.

Answer (score 2):

OrderedDict is mutable:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict.fromkeys('abcde')
d['a']= 'aretor'
print(d)

>> OrderedDict([('a', 'aretor'), ('b', None), ('c', None), ('d', None), ('e', None)])

print(d['a'])
>> aretor
```